# how to dispose a incoming email and then send some words back using google-app-engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, incoming-mail

I read the doc:

```
from google.appengine.api import mail
mail.send_mail(sender="support@example.com",
                  to="Albert Johnson <Albert.Johnson@example.com>",
                  subject="Your account has been approved",
                  body="""
    Dear Albert:

Your example.com account has been approved.  You can now visit
http://www.example.com/ and sign in using your Google Account to
access new features.

Please let us know if you have any questions.

The example.com Team
""")
```

I know how to send an email using GAE, but how to check an incoming email and then do something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the page in the docs that deals with how to [receive email](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail.html).